# Maximo setWhere() query to get distinct results?

Tags: java, tivoli, maximo

I'm trying to do this SQL query:
`select distinct wonum from invreserve where location='01' order by wonum;`

How can this be converted to a setWhere() query? I've tried:

`invreserveSet.setWhere("(1 = 1) and wonum in (select distinct wonum from invreserve where location='01')");`

Comment: Try making your sub-select select distinct ir2.wonum from invreserve ir2 where ir2.location='01'). I believe Maximo assumes the query will be select * from invreserve, so your where clause may not be explicit enough to process correctly.

Comment: Hm, ok will try that.. Seems true that Maximo does a "select *"

Answer (score 2):

work with something like this:

```
select invreserveid from invreserve where invreserveid in (select invreserveid from invreserve invr2 where location like '%B%'
and invreserveid = (select max(invreserveid) from invreserve invr3 where invr3.location = invr2.location and invr3.wonum = invr2.wonum)) 
;
```

so your where clause would be the same as this ones except your location wildcard would be different.

Comment: I will try the normalize